# MySQL error #1451 caused through custom function call

Tags: mysql, database, function, insert, mysql-error-1452

I made a quite large function with lots of selects/updates to fill all tables with data. Just tried filling the tables but I received an #1452 error when calling the function

```
SELECT insert_tune("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S")
```

where the error looks like

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`rbase`.`tunes`, CONSTRAINT `tunes_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`riddim_fk`) REFERENCES `riddims` (`riddim_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

The database layout looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE artists (
    artist_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    artist_name varchar(100) UNIQUE,
    artist_aka varchar(255) UNIQUE
) ENGINE = 'InnoDB';

CREATE TABLE labels (
    label_id SMALLINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    label_name varchar(100) UNIQUE,
    label_aka varchar(255) UNIQUE
) ENGINE = 'InnoDB';

CREATE TABLE producers (
    producer_id SMALLINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    producer_forename varchar(100),
    producer_nickname varchar(100) UNIQUE,
    producer_lastname varchar(100)
) ENGINE = 'InnoDB';

CREATE TABLE years (
    year_id TINYINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    year_value varchar(4) UNIQUE
) ENGINE = 'InnoDB';

CREATE TABLE genres (
    genre_id TINYINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    genre_name varchar(10) UNIQUE
) ENGINE = 'InnoDB';

CREATE TABLE flags (
    flag_id TINYINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    flag_name varchar(12) UNIQUE
) ENGINE = 'InnoDB';

CREATE TABLE tags (
    tag_id SMALLINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    tag_name varchar(16) UNIQUE
) ENGINE = 'InnoDB';

CREATE TABLE sources (
    source_id TINYINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    source_name varchar(30) UNIQUE
) ENGINE = 'InnoDB';

CREATE TABLE riddims (
    riddim_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    riddim_name varchar(40) UNIQUE,
    riddim_aka varchar(255) UNIQUE,
    genre_fk TINYINT,
    youtube varchar(11) UNIQUE,
    image varchar(11) UNIQUE,
    FOREIGN KEY (genre_fk) REFERENCES genres(genre_id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = 'InnoDB';

CREATE TABLE tunes (
    tune_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    riddim_fk INT DEFAULT NULL,
    artist_fk INT DEFAULT NULL,
    tune_name varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
    tune_aka varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    label_fk SMALLINT DEFAULT NULL,
    producer_fk SMALLINT DEFAULT NULL,
    year_fk TINYINT DEFAULT NULL,   
    lyrics TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
    flag_fk TINYINT,
    tag_fk SMALLINT,
    source_fk TINYINT,
    last_modified TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    FOREIGN KEY (riddim_fk) REFERENCES riddims(riddim_id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (artist_fk) REFERENCES artists(artist_id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (producer_fk) REFERENCES producers(producer_id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (year_fk) REFERENCES years(year_id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (flag_fk) REFERENCES flags(flag_id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (tag_fk) REFERENCES tags(tag_id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (source_fk) REFERENCES sources(source_id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = 'InnoDB';
```

And the function that I'm using to fill the tables looks like

```
CREATE FUNCTION insert_tune(
        riddim      varchar(40),
        riddim_a    varchar(255),
        yt          varchar(11),
        img         varchar(11),
        artist      varchar(100),
        artist_a    varchar(255),
        tune        varchar(60),
        tune_a      varchar(255),
        genre       varchar(10),
        label       varchar(100),
        label_a     varchar(255),
        producer_fn varchar(100),
        producer_nn varchar(100),
        producer_ln varchar(100),
        year        varchar(4),
        lrx         TEXT,
        flag        varchar(12),
        tag         varchar(16),
        source      varchar(30)
    )
    RETURNS INT
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

    DECLARE cRiddim, cArtist, cLabel, cProducer, cRiddimArtist, cRiddimTune, cArtistTune, cRiddimArtistTune INT;

    /* Testing if the tables already contain certain records/entries */
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM riddims WHERE riddim_name = riddim INTO cRiddim;
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM artists WHERE artist_name = artist INTO cArtist;
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM labels WHERE label_name = label INTO cLabel;
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM producers WHERE producer_nickname = producer_nn INTO cProducer;
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tunes WHERE artist_fk = (SELECT artist_id FROM artists WHERE artist_name = artist) AND tune_name = tune AND ISNULL(riddim_fk) INTO cArtistTune;
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tunes WHERE riddim_fk = (SELECT riddim_id FROM riddims WHERE riddim_name = riddim) AND tune_name = tune AND ISNULL(artist_fk) INTO cRiddimTune;
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tunes WHERE riddim_fk = (SELECT riddim_id FROM riddims WHERE riddim_name = riddim) AND artist_fk = (SELECT artist_id FROM artists WHERE artist_name = artist) AND ISNULL(tune_name) INTO cRiddimArtist;
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tunes WHERE riddim_fk = (SELECT riddim_id FROM riddims WHERE riddim_name = riddim) AND artist_fk = (SELECT artist_id FROM artists WHERE artist_name = artist) AND tune_name = tune INTO cRiddimArtistTune;

    /* 
       ##########
       # GENRES #
       ##########
    */
    IF genre NOT IN ('') AND NOT ISNULL(genre) THEN
        INSERT IGNORE INTO genres (genre_name) VALUES (genre);
    END IF;

    /* 
       ###########
       # RIDDIMS #
       ###########
    */
    IF cRiddim < 1 AND riddim NOT IN ('') AND NOT ISNULL(riddim) THEN
        INSERT INTO riddims (
            riddim_name, 
            riddim_aka, 
            youtube, 
            image
        ) 
    VALUES (
        riddim,
        IF(riddim_a NOT IN (''), riddim_a, NULL), 
        IF(yt NOT IN (''), yt, NULL), 
        IF(img NOT IN (''), img, NULL)
    );
    ELSE
        UPDATE riddims SET 
            riddim_aka = IFNULL(riddim_aka, IF(NOT ISNULL(riddim_a) AND riddim_a NOT IN (''), riddim_a, NULL)),
            genre_fk = IFNULL(genre_fk, IF(NOT ISNULL(genre) AND genre NOT IN (''), (SELECT genre_id FROM genres WHERE genre_name = genre), NULL)),
            youtube = IFNULL(youtube, IF(NOT ISNULL(youtube) AND youtube NOT IN (''), youtube, NULL)),
            image = IFNULL(img, IF(NOT ISNULL(img) AND img NOT IN (''), img, NULL))
        WHERE 
            riddim_name = riddim;
    END IF;


    /* 
       ###########
      # ARTISTS #
       ###########
    */  
    IF cArtist < 1 AND artist NOT IN ('') AND NOT ISNULL(artist) THEN
        INSERT INTO artists (
            artist_name, 
            artist_aka
        ) 
        VALUES (
            artist,
            IF(artist_a NOT IN (''), artist_a, NULL)
        );
    ELSE
        UPDATE artists SET 
            artist_aka = IFNULL(artist_aka, IF(NOT ISNULL(artist_a) AND artist_a NOT IN (''), artist_a, NULL)) 
        WHERE 
            artist_name = artist;
    END IF;


    /* 
       ##########
       # LABELS #
       ##########
    */
    IF cLabel < 1 AND label NOT IN ('') AND NOT ISNULL(label) THEN
        INSERT INTO labels (
            label_name,
            label_aka
        )
        VALUES (
            label,
            IF(label_a NOT IN (''), label_a, NULL)
        );
    ELSE
        UPDATE labels SET 
            label_aka = IFNULL(label_aka, IF(NOT ISNULL(label_a) AND label_a NOT IN (''), label_a, NULL)) 
        WHERE label_name = label;
    END IF;


    /* 
       #############
       # PRODUCERS #
       #############
    */
    IF cProducer < 1 AND producer_nn NOT IN ('') AND NOT ISNULL(producer_nn) THEN
        INSERT INTO producers (
            producer_forename,
            producer_nickname,
            producer_lastname
        )
        VALUES (
            IF(producer_fn NOT IN (''), producer_fn, NULL),
            producer_nn,
            IF(producer_ln NOT IN (''), producer_ln, NULL)
        );
    ELSE
        UPDATE producers SET 
            producer_forename = IFNULL(producer_forename, IF(NOT ISNULL(producer_fn) AND producer_fn NOT IN (''), producer_fn, NULL)),
            producer_lastname = IFNULL(producer_lastname, IF(NOT ISNULL(producer_ln) AND producer_ln NOT IN (''), producer_ln, NULL))
        WHERE
            producer_nickname = producer_nn;
    END IF;


    /* 
       #########
       # YEARS #
       #########
    */
    IF year NOT IN ('') AND NOT ISNULL(year) THEN
        INSERT IGNORE INTO years (year_value) VALUES (year);
    END IF;


    /* 
       #########
       # FLAGS #
       #########
    */  
    IF flag NOT IN ('') AND NOT ISNULL(flag) THEN
        INSERT IGNORE INTO flags (flag_name) VALUES (flag);
    END IF;


    /* 
       ########
       # TAGS #
       ########
    */  
    IF tag NOT IN ('') AND NOT ISNULL(tag) THEN
        INSERT IGNORE INTO tags (tag_name) VALUES (tag);
    END IF;


    /* 
       ###########
      # SOURCES #
       ###########
       */       
    IF source NOT IN ('') AND NOT ISNULL(source) THEN
        INSERT IGNORE INTO sources (source_name) VALUES (source);
    END IF;


    /* 
       #########
       # TUNES #
   #########
    */
    IF cArtistTune > 0 THEN
        UPDATE tunes SET 
            riddim_fk = IFNULL(riddim_fk, IF(NOT ISNULL(riddim) AND riddim NOT IN (''), (SELECT riddim_id FROM riddims WHERE riddim_name = riddim), NULL)),
            tune_aka = IFNULL(tune_aka, IF(NOT ISNULL(tune_a) AND tune_a NOT IN (''), tune_a, NULL)),
            label_fk = IFNULL(label_fk, IF(NOT ISNULL(label) AND label NOT IN (''), (SELECT label_id FROM labels WHERE label_name = label), NULL)),
            producer_fk = IFNULL(producer_fk, IF(NOT ISNULL(producer_nn) AND producer_nn NOT IN (''), (SELECT producer_id FROM producers WHERE producer_nickname = producer_nn), NULL)),
            year_fk = IFNULL(year_fk, IF(NOT ISNULL(year) AND year NOT IN (''), (SELECT year_id FROM years WHERE year_value = year), NULL)),
            lyrics = IFNULL(lyrics, IF(NOT ISNULL(lrx) AND lrx NOT IN (''), lrx, NULL)),
            flag_fk = IFNULL(flag_fk, IF(NOT ISNULL(flag) AND flag NOT IN (''), (SELECT flag_id FROM flags WHERE flag_name = flag), NULL)),
            tag_fk = IFNULL(tag_fk, IF(NOT ISNULL(tag) AND tag NOT IN (''), (SELECT tag_id FROM tags WHERE tag_name = tag), NULL)),
            source_fk = IFNULL(source_fk, IF(NOT ISNULL(source) AND source NOT IN (''), (SELECT source_id FROM sources WHERE source_name = source), NULL))
        WHERE 
            tune_name = tune AND artist_fk = (SELECT artist_id FROM artists WHERE artist_name = artist);
    ELSEIF cRiddimTune > 0 THEN
        UPDATE tunes SET 
            artist_fk = IFNULL(artist_fk, IF(NOT ISNULL(artist) AND artist NOT IN (''), (SELECT artist_id FROM artists WHERE artist_name = artist), NULL)),
            tune_aka = IFNULL(tune_aka, IF(NOT ISNULL(tune_a) AND tune_a NOT IN (''), tune_a, NULL)),
            label_fk = IFNULL(label_fk, IF(NOT ISNULL(label) AND label NOT IN (''), (SELECT label_id FROM labels WHERE label_name = label), NULL)),
            producer_fk = IFNULL(producer_fk, IF(NOT ISNULL(producer_nn) AND producer_nn NOT IN (''), (SELECT producer_id FROM producers WHERE producer_nickname = producer_nn), NULL)),
            year_fk = IFNULL(year_fk, IF(NOT ISNULL(year) AND year NOT IN (''), (SELECT year_id FROM years WHERE year_value = year), NULL)),
            lyrics = IFNULL(lyrics, IF(NOT ISNULL(lrx) AND lrx NOT IN (''), lrx, NULL)),
            flag_fk = IFNULL(flag_fk, IF(NOT ISNULL(flag) AND flag NOT IN (''), (SELECT flag_id FROM flags WHERE flag_name = flag), NULL)),
            tag_fk = IFNULL(tag_fk, IF(NOT ISNULL(tag) AND tag NOT IN (''), (SELECT tag_id FROM tags WHERE tag_name = tag), NULL)),
            source_fk = IFNULL(source_fk, IF(NOT ISNULL(source) AND source NOT IN (''), (SELECT source_id FROM sources WHERE source_name = source), NULL))
        WHERE
            tune_name = tune AND riddim_fk = (SELECT riddim_id FROM riddims WHERE riddim_name = riddim);
    ELSEIF cRiddimArtist > 0 THEN
        UPDATE tunes SET 
            tune_name = IFNULL(tune_name, IF(NOT ISNULL(tune) AND tune NOT IN (''), tune, NULL)),
            tune_aka = IFNULL(tune_aka, IF(NOT ISNULL(tune_a) AND tune_a NOT IN (''), tune_a, NULL)),
            label_fk = IFNULL(label_fk, IF(NOT ISNULL(label) AND label NOT IN (''), (SELECT label_id FROM labels WHERE label_name = label), NULL)),
            producer_fk = IFNULL(producer_fk, IF(NOT ISNULL(producer_nn) AND producer_nn NOT IN (''), (SELECT producer_id FROM producers WHERE producer_nickname = producer_nn), NULL)),
            year_fk = IFNULL(year_fk, IF(NOT ISNULL(year) AND year NOT IN (''), (SELECT year_id FROM years WHERE year_value = year), NULL)),
            lyrics = IFNULL(lyrics, IF(NOT ISNULL(lrx) AND lrx NOT IN (''), lrx, NULL)),
            flag_fk = IFNULL(flag_fk, IF(NOT ISNULL(flag) AND flag NOT IN (''), (SELECT flag_id FROM flags WHERE flag_name = flag), NULL)),
            tag_fk = IFNULL(tag_fk, IF(NOT ISNULL(tag) AND tag NOT IN (''), (SELECT tag_id FROM tags WHERE tag_name = tag), NULL)),
            source_fk = IFNULL(source_fk, IF(NOT ISNULL(source) AND source NOT IN (''), (SELECT source_id FROM sources WHERE source_name = source), NULL))
        WHERE
            artist_fk = (SELECT artist_id FROM artists WHERE artist_name = artist) AND riddim_fk = (SELECT riddim_id FROM riddims WHERE riddim_name = riddim);
    ELSEIF cRiddimArtistTune < 1 THEN
        IF tune NOT IN ('') AND NOT ISNULL(tune) AND artist NOT IN ('') AND NOT ISNULL(artist) THEN
            INSERT INTO tunes (
                riddim_fk,
                artist_fk,
                tune_name,
                tune_aka,
                label_fk,
                producer_fk,
                year_fk,
                lyrics,
                flag_fk,
                tag_fk,
                source_fk
            )
            VALUES (
                IF(NOT ISNULL(riddim) AND riddim NOT IN (''), riddim, NULL),
                (SELECT artist_id FROM artists WHERE artist_name = artist),
                tune,
                IF(NOT ISNULL(tune_a) AND tune_a NOT IN (''), tune_a, NULL),
                IF(NOT ISNULL(label) AND label NOT IN (''), (SELECT label_id FROM labels WHERE label_name = label), NULL),
                IF(NOT ISNULL(producer_nn) AND producer_nn NOT IN (''), (SELECT producer_id FROM producers WHERE producer_nickname = producer_nn), NULL),
                IF(NOT ISNULL(year) AND year NOT IN (''), (SELECT year_id FROM years WHERE year_value = year), NULL),
                IF(NOT ISNULL(lrx) AND lrx NOT IN (''), lrx, NULL),
                IF(NOT ISNULL(flag) AND flag NOT IN (''), (SELECT flag_id FROM flags WHERE flag_name = flag), NULL),
                IF(NOT ISNULL(tag) AND tag NOT IN (''), (SELECT tag_id FROM tags WHERE tag_name = tag), NULL),
                IF(NOT ISNULL(source) AND source NOT IN (''), (SELECT source_id FROM sources WHERE source_name = source), NULL)
        );
        END IF;
        IF tune NOT IN ('') AND NOT ISNULL(tune) AND riddim NOT IN ('') AND NOT ISNULL(riddim) THEN
            INSERT INTO tunes (
                riddim_fk,
                artist_fk,
                tune_name,
                tune_aka,
                label_fk,
                producer_fk,
                year_fk,
                lyrics,
                flag_fk,
                tag_fk,
                source_fk
            )
            VALUES (
                (SELECT riddim_id FROM riddims WHERE riddim_name = riddim),
                IF(NOT ISNULL(artist) AND artist NOT IN (''), (SELECT artist_id FROM artists WHERE artist_name = artist), NULL),
                tune,
                IF(NOT ISNULL(tune_a) AND tune_a NOT IN (''), tune_a, NULL),
                IF(NOT ISNULL(label) AND label NOT IN (''), (SELECT label_id FROM labels WHERE label_name = label), NULL),
                IF(NOT ISNULL(producer_nn) AND producer_nn NOT IN (''), (SELECT producer_id FROM producers WHERE producer_nickname = producer_nn), NULL),
                IF(NOT ISNULL(year) AND year NOT IN (''), (SELECT year_id FROM years WHERE year_value = year), NULL),
                IF(NOT ISNULL(lrx) AND lrx NOT IN (''), lrx, NULL),
                IF(NOT ISNULL(flag) AND flag NOT IN (''), (SELECT flag_id FROM flags WHERE flag_name = flag), NULL),
                IF(NOT ISNULL(tag) AND tag NOT IN (''), (SELECT tag_id FROM tags WHERE tag_name = tag), NULL),
                IF(NOT ISNULL(source) AND source NOT IN (''), (SELECT source_id FROM sources WHERE source_name = source), NULL)
            );
        END IF;
        IF artist NOT IN ('') AND NOT ISNULL(artist) AND riddim NOT IN ('') AND NOT ISNULL(riddim) THEN
            INSERT INTO tunes (
                riddim_fk,
                artist_fk,
                tune_name,
                tune_aka,
                label_fk,
                producer_fk,
                year_fk,
                lyrics,
                flag_fk,
                tag_fk,
                source_fk
            )
            VALUES (
                (SELECT riddim_id FROM riddims WHERE riddim_name = riddim),
                (SELECT artist_id FROM artists WHERE artist_name = artist),
                IF(NOT ISNULL(tune) AND tune NOT IN (''), tune, NULL),
                IF(NOT ISNULL(tune_a) AND tune_a NOT IN (''), tune_a, NULL),
                IF(NOT ISNULL(label) AND label NOT IN (''), (SELECT label_id FROM labels WHERE label_name = label), NULL),
                IF(NOT ISNULL(producer_nn) AND producer_nn NOT IN (''), (SELECT producer_id FROM producers WHERE producer_nickname = producer_nn), NULL),
                IF(NOT ISNULL(year) AND year NOT IN (''), (SELECT year_id FROM years WHERE year_value = year), NULL),
                IF(NOT ISNULL(lrx) AND lrx NOT IN (''), lrx, NULL),
                IF(NOT ISNULL(flag) AND flag NOT IN (''), (SELECT flag_id FROM flags WHERE flag_name = flag), NULL),
                IF(NOT ISNULL(tag) AND tag NOT IN (''), (SELECT tag_id FROM tags WHERE tag_name = tag), NULL),
                IF(NOT ISNULL(source) AND source NOT IN (''), (SELECT source_id FROM sources WHERE source_name = source), NULL)
            );
        END IF;
    ELSEIF cRiddimArtistTune > 0 THEN
        UPDATE tunes SET 
            tune_aka = IFNULL(tune_aka, IF(NOT ISNULL(tune_a) AND tune_a NOT IN (''), tune_a, NULL)),
            label_fk = IFNULL(label_fk, IF(NOT ISNULL(label) AND label NOT IN (''), (SELECT label_id FROM labels WHERE label_name = label), NULL)),
            producer_fk = IFNULL(producer_fk, IF(NOT ISNULL(producer_nn) AND producer_nn NOT IN (''), (SELECT producer_id FROM producers WHERE producer_nickname = producer_nn), NULL)),
            year_fk = IFNULL(year_fk, IF(NOT ISNULL(year) AND year NOT IN (''), (SELECT year_id FROM years WHERE year_value = year), NULL)),
            lyrics = IFNULL(lyrics, IF(NOT ISNULL(lrx) AND lrx NOT IN (''), lrx, NULL)),
            flag_fk = IFNULL(flag_fk, IF(NOT ISNULL(flag) AND flag NOT IN (''), (SELECT flag_id FROM flags WHERE flag_name = flag), NULL)),
            tag_fk = IFNULL(tag_fk, IF(NOT ISNULL(tag) AND tag NOT IN (''), (SELECT tag_id FROM tags WHERE tag_name = tag), NULL)),
            source_fk = IFNULL(source_fk, IF(NOT ISNULL(source) AND source NOT IN (''), (SELECT source_id FROM sources WHERE source_name = source), NULL))
        WHERE
            artist_fk = (SELECT artist_id FROM artists WHERE artist_name = artist) AND riddim_fk = (SELECT riddim_id FROM riddims WHERE riddim_name = riddim) AND tune_name = tune;
    END IF;

    RETURN 0; /** add more/better returns & values to determine what data was inserted **/
END
```

To all you database wizards out there, bear with me please, I'm new to this stuff so the function might be a bit bloated.

Anyways, some research has shown me that the error mentioned above occurs when there's a foreign key column pointing to a non-existant row in the parent table. The odd part is that my tables are all empty.
It may also occur when the foreign key column is - by mistake - pointing to its own table - but that's not the case here either (as far as I understood similiar problems that I read).

Pretty annoying is that I am not allowed to use SELECT CONCAT() (for debugging purposes) within the function's scope, so I do not really get why/where the error occurs, but I assume it pops up as soon as the part of the function is processed that inserts data into tunes.riddim_fk.

I also set riddim_id, genre_id and so on (parent tables' IDs) to PRIMARY KEY and AUTO_INCREMENT, now phpMyAdmin shows me "NULL: no" for those columns, even though I did not specify "NOT NULL". I assume one of the keys is automatically setting the columns to NOT NULL.

May that be causing the error as I am adding NULL to the ie. riddim_fk column, if the function parameter "riddim" was set to "" (empty string)?
I assume not as in my actual function test call (like above) I did not pass empty strings as parameter(s) to the function.

Help is appreciated!

**EDIT:** Typos.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem! It indeed was a mistake by myself trying to INSERT varchar into INT fk column.

```
        )
        VALUES (
            IF(NOT ISNULL(riddim) AND riddim NOT IN (''), riddim, NULL),
            (SELECT artist_id FROM artists WHERE artist_name = artist),
            tune,
```

ofcourse needs to be altered to

```
        )
        VALUES (
            IF(NOT ISNULL(riddim) AND riddim NOT IN (''), (SELECT riddim_id FROM riddims WHERE riddim_name = riddim), NULL),
            (SELECT artist_id FROM artists WHERE artist_name = artist),
            tune,
```

Took me quite a while to find that one.